# formatting json file with vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

How can I show the output from json file with vue.js
this is my example:

```
access_type: {
    "id": 1210765901,
    "version": "17",
    "creation_time": "2015-04-02 15:09:02",
    "change_time": "2017-01-06 02:51:01",
    "fixnet_id": "BN00002969937",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "xipsib_lan_ip": null
}
```

I wanna make the output like this:

```
id: 1210765901
version: 17
...
```

this is my script:

```
<div class="card-content">
    <pre v-for="(info, index) in activeInfos" :key="index">
        <li>{{ type }}: {{ info}}</li> 
    </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code?

Comment: @evolutionxbox i have the output like example that i show it and i wanna formating the result

Comment: what kind of formatting?

Comment: @choasia that the result is like this: id: 1210765901 and nor like this "id": 1210765901

Comment: Have you converted the json data into an object?

Comment: check my test here: https://codesandbox.io/s/lpo41rx2rl

Comment: @choasia yes  computed: {
    siteObject() {
      return this.site;
    }

Comment: The snippet makes little sense to me. I think you can provide a runnable example in the question.

Comment: @choasia thanks but this infos are changing each hour i cant make it fixe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help
i have found the solution:

```
<vue-tabs class="row" direction="vertical" value="Description">
          <div v-for="(siteParts, index) in sitePartLine">
            <v-tab :title="sitePartLine[index].serial_no" v-if="sitePartLine[index]">
              <div class="description text-left" v-for="siteParts in sitePartLine">
                {{ siteParts.fixnet_id }}
                <div class="description text-left" v-for="item in siteParts.part_attributes">
                  <small><strong>{{item.x_name}}</strong> {{item.x_value}}</small>
                </div>
              </div>
            </v-tab>
          </div>

        </vue-tabs>
```